# using sp_send_dbmail with join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job, sql-job

I am trying to run the following as a job on `Sql Server Agent` and I don't get an email.

I think there is something wrong with the way I am representing tables in the `inner join` because if I replace the query with a simple query without joins, the task works .

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'TEST_DEV',
    @recipients = 'xxx@gmail.com',
    @query = ' select 
            Percentage = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),100 - (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT case when PD.Exception  != ' ' then PD.Id  END) as float)/CAST(COUNT(PD.Id) as float)*100))
         from 
                DataBaseName.dbo.Product P INNER JOIN DataBaseName.dbo.LogProduct PD 
                ON P.LogId = PD.LogId

                WHERE   
                ResponseTime < GETDATE() and  RequestTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -150, GETDATE())
                ' ,
    @subject = 'Test',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the above answers helped me . What I did to troubleshoot my issue is that instead of a query I used a stored procedure. It works fine now.

```
@query = 'exec DatabaseName.dbo.storedprocedure'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use joins in my @query parameter all the time without error.  The fact that you don't get an email sent is typically an indication that the query did not parse successfully at run time.

Does the query, with joins, run in SSMS directly?  You might consider creating a variable @ResponseTime TYPE??? and SETing the value of the Variable prior to the send_dbmail and then simply passing that value in replacing the syntax with the @ResponseTime

Answer (score 1):

I did notice a formatting issue.  You need to use '' to escape a quote '.  This might be your first issue with your query.

If you have Adventure Works installed, run the below query from my database mail [blog](http://craftydba.com/?p=1025) entry.  Just replace the profile name and recipients mail address.  This will test the sp_send_dbmail() function.

```
-- Send with query results as an attachment
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'The Public Profile',
@recipients = 'john@craftydba.com',
@query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.WorkOrder
WHERE DueDate > ''2006-04-30''
AND DATEDIFF(dd, ''2006-04-30'', DueDate) < 2' ,
@subject = 'Work Order Count',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
GO
```

If this does work, then test your query in SSMS to make sure you are getting results.